# Is this a aloe vera plant?

Tags: identification, cactus, aloe

So I had this plant for around 1 year and lastly I was wondering if this is a Aloe vera plant? Kind of looks like it but I'm still unsure. If it's not that what is it? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not Aloe barbadensis, commonly referred to as Aloe vera. It's not an Aloe of any sort, I think it's some sort of Haworthia. It looks like Haworthia limifolia. See image below.

[image: H. limifolia]

Answer (score 0):

With a quick search on google images, yes it is: http://practicalgardenplants.com/aloe-vera-widely-known-healing-powers/

Comment: This is not Aloe barbadensis, commonly referred to as Aloe vera. It's not an Aloe of any sort, I think it's some sort of Haworthia. It looks like Haworthia limifolia.

Comment: @TimNevins - can you make this an answer please - I believe you're right...